# CAKEPHP2: How to keep the input fields after pressing the paginate in cakephp2?

Tags: forms, pagination, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

Just like in the title, I have a form in cakephp2 where you can select basic information
and can input names and such.In this page there is a pagination and what I want to do is to
keep the input field and the selected options to be there even if you press the pagination
button.

```
<td><?php
    echo $this->Form->input('SpotBest.status', array(
                'type' => 'radio',
                'legend' => false,
                'options' => SpotBest::$STATUSES,
                ));
        ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe setting a "default" parameter?

```
<td><?php
echo $this->Form->input('SpotBest.status', array(
            'type' => 'radio',
            'legend' => false,
            'options' => SpotBest::$STATUSES,
            'default' => $_REQUEST['data']['SpotBest']['status'])
            ));
    ?></td>
```

According to [CakePHP Cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Core-Helpers/Form.html#id2) this should be the way...